# C: How can I edit a C-string in a function without using malloc

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, c-strings

I have a `string` in `main` and I would like to pass the address of that string to a function that will edit the contents of that string. I do not want to use malloc.

My code currently looks like this:

```
int main(){
        char* str = "Hello";
        char* para1[] = {"Tea", "Coffee"};

        printf("str: %s\n para1: %s\n", str, para1[0]);

        my_func(str, &para1);

        printf("str: %s\n para1: %s\n", str, para1[0]);

        return 1;
}

int my_func(char* str, char** para1){
        printf("str: %s\n", str);
        str[0] = 'W';
        para1[0] = "Popcorn";

        return 1;
}
```

I don't understand how I can change the first letter of the string from `H` to `W`

Could you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1) `char* str = "Hello";` --> `char str[] = "Hello";` 2) `my_func(str, &para1);` --> `my_func(str, para1);` Also You must have a prototype before you use this function.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY In C89 this function could be called without prototype , and since unfortunately even modern compilers still default to C89 mode, there may be no warning

Comment: Never use tabs for indenting.  Each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set for personal preferences.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals are read-only. When you define:

```
char* string_literal = "Hello";
```

You're getting a pointer to the text "Hello" that resides in read-only memory.

If you declare this as a char array:

```
char string[] = "Hello";
```

Then you can modify the contents of `string` with array index notation:

```
string[0] = "W";
```

Now, you can replace a pointer to a string literal with a pointer to another string literal. For example,

```
string_literal = "New string literal";
```

because here what you're actually doing is reassigning the pointer called "`string_literal`" to point to another address in memory. The pointer itself is writeable, but the memory to which it points is read-only. This is why your assignment to para1 succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

**String literals** are *unmodifiable*, since they are usually stored in the *immutable data section* of your exe.

---

It's not about your function, take this toy example for instance:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* str = "Hello";
    str[0] = 'g';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

It should result in a runtime error, I got:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
Bus error: 10
```

There tons of information on the subject, thus I won't expand more.

Comment: I do not know who upvoted me, but his/her vote, made me reach the 20k rep mliestone!!! :D

Comment: congratulations!!  (*^_^)_∠※☆PAN！

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ありがとう, who knows maybe some day I can follow your example!

Answer (score 2):

String literals are stored in [read-only part of the memory](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294748/why-are-c-string-literals-read-only), so you cannot modify them.